# WPF: ListItem does not receive focus when you press the button located on this ListItem

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datatemplate, wpf-4.0

I have a `ListBox` with a `DataTemplate`. The template has a `Button` on it. Each item in the list shows the entity.

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0"
             x:Name="ThemesList"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Themes}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTheme}" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ThemeListTemplate}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ThemeListTemplate">
    <Grid Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
          Margin="10">

          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition/>
              <RowDefinition/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <Button Grid.Row="0" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Style="{StaticResource ElementButton}"
                  Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ThemeEditorViewModel.OpenThemeEditorCommand, ElementName=ThemesBacklog}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=ThemesList}">

                <TextBlock Text="Edit"/>
          </Button>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Style="{StaticResource ElementButton}"
                Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ThemeDeleteCommand, ElementName=ThemesBacklog}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=ThemesList}">

                <TextBlock Text="Delete"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

When you click on `Button` in the command is passed the property value `SelectedItem`. When you click on `ListItem` and then click `Button` - all fine. When I at once click on the `Button` - in the command is passed null. That is `ListItem` does not receive focus when you press the button located on this `ListItem`. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could examine the `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` property on the `ListBoxItems` in a trigger, to find out whether a child (like your button), has focus, and set `IsSelected` to true if that is the case.

You do this by setting the `ItemContainerStyle` like this:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Won't that this trigger leave item selected if user selects other items with the mouse? mouse click not always moves keyboard focus to the clicked element.

Comment: Hmm, nope that's not something I have experienced.